# Make module method available without scoping

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do something very similar to rspec's `describe`.

Say I have a module in `my_mod.rb`

```
module MyMod
  def say_hello(name)
    puts "hello #{name}"
  end
end
```

And I use it in another file `foo.rb`

```
include MyMod # without the include it cannot find say_hello

say_hello "world"
```

My question is - how do I get this to work like rspec, i.e. `require`-ing the module should make the methods available, without having to do `MyMod.say_hello`.

Comment: You can't. Rspec does all the `include`ing for you, but it still has to happen. If you want to do what Rspec does, write a custom front-end program. You'll notice that you run your tests with `rspec <path/to/test>`, not `ruby <path/to/test`>.

Answer (score 0):

Change your original `foo.rb`, replacing `include` with `extend`.
This way, you can use `say_hello "world"`

But, if you really want to use `require`, define the method without the module:

`my_mod.rb`:

```
  def say_hello(name)
    puts "hello #{name}"
  end
```

then, in `foo.rb`:

```
require 'my_mod'

say_hello "world"
```